# Need Help on DC Jack and MOSFET Functionality Circuit

Tags: power, mosfet, dc

I'm trying to build a specific DC Jack that is supplying 24V power. The main feature of it is there is **no voltage in the VCC pin in the jack until a barrel is connected** to it. So the **VCC pin only gets 24V when the shunt pin in the jack is disconnected from the ground pin**.

My initial idea is to use a P-channel MOSFET and came with this idea in the schematic below. But I realized **this circuit will do the opposite of what I want**. It will supply 24V when no barrel is connected and stops supplying 24V when a barrel is connected. I can't seem to think of a circuit to make the DC jack behave in the way I want it to. Maybe you guys know a way or suggestions?

[image]

**EDITS:**

Here is a new schematic based on the suggestion of using a N-MOSFET to inverse the signal:

[image]

Added the voltage divider back. Vgs2 (Vgs for the N-MOSFEt) can only handle 20V so the a voltage divider is added back.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can invert the signal with another FET.

Drive a N channel FET with the contacts. When grounded, N FET is off, and does not turn the P FET on. When contact is released, N FET can get gate voltage and turns on, pulling P FET gate low to turn on the connector voltage.

Comment: Interesting! I took what you said and made a schematic and posted in the OP. Does this look right?

Comment: Right, except that depending on the FET, 24V might be too much for Vgs, so your original idea of using resistor dividers to limit to 12V Vgs might be a good idea. But it would work as it is if the Vgs tolerates the supply.

Comment: Ok! Thanks so much for your idea!

Comment: So I picked my MOSFET and made the changes in the schematic. On the datasheet, the P-MOSFET has drain source voltage rating of 30V and Vgs rating of 25V with a threshold of 3V. I decided to add the voltage divider back anyways to make Vgs1 12V. For the N-MOSFET, it has Vds rating of 20V and Vgs of 8V with threshold of 1.5V. The voltage divider should make the Vgs on the N-mosfet 3V. and the voltage divider on the on the P-MOSFET should make the Vds on the N-mosfet below 20V??